# Show that this linear operator is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a Banach space, and $T$ is a linear operator on $E$, furthermore,it's assumed that $$\sup_{||x||=1}|f(T(x))|<\infty,\forall f\in E^*;$$
$$\inf_{||x||=1}\sup_{||f||=1}|f(T(x)|>0;$$ and if $\forall x\in E$,$f(T(x)=0$ , then $f=0$.

Under these conditions, please show that $T$ is surjective.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first condition, you can deduce that $T$ is bounded, using uniform boundedness principle:

$$
\sup_{||x||=1}|f(T(x))|<\infty,\forall f\in E^*
$$
$$
\implies ||f(T)||<\infty,\forall f\in E^*
$$
$$
\implies ||T||<\infty
$$
first step by definition of $||\cdot||$, second by UBP (there's probably a quicker way to show this, but it's been a while since FA).

The second hypothesis will allow you to conclude the operator is bounded below, and in turn, that the range is closed:
if $Tx_n \to y$
$$
|T(x_m) - T(x_n)| > C|x_m - x_n|
$$
so $x_n \to x$ by completeness. Since $Tx_n \to Tx$, we have $Tx = y$.

The third hypothesis prevents the range from being a (non-trivial) closed subspace (if it were, you could find a non-zero $f$ such that $f(y) = 0$ for all $y$ in the subspace, by Hahn-Banach).

Comment: So how does this show that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: I filled in the missing details.

Comment: Nice, I'll have to read it later though, since I have to do something else right now.

Comment: Thanks.indeed,for the boundedness of the operator,a direct use of UBP,may get that $\{Tx;||x||=1\}$is bounded,so T is bounded by definition